# Clicking a dialog before page loads in protractor

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, selenium, protractor

Currently I am attempting to click a dialog box that appears before a page loads. I am using the browser.get(extentionHere) function to load the page in a manner resembling this:

`it(..., function(){
     browser.get('#/frontPage);
     element(dialogIdentifier).click();`

When the page loads Protractor does nothing until a timeout, an investigation into this behavior led me to find that it was the result of the page hanging as the rest of the page 'waited' for the dialog to be clicked.  In essence the URL was meaningless as Protractor thinks the page has not loaded and treats the dialog as more of a browser feature (it is not) instead of the webpage.  Hence, the element(...).click() did not execute, and of course, the program could not continue.
In attempting to find a solution I found the function [browser.executeAsyncScript](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeAsyncScript) which I thought might allow me to execute multiple functions in an order.  My, albeit ignorant, attempt led me to this:

```
    browser.executeAsyncScript('browser.get("#/frontPage")').then(function () {  
          element(dialogIdentifier)).click();
    });
```

which, as implied by my asking this question, did not work (giving me some sort of "browser is not a function" error), if I am even using this function correctly for the correct purpose it would seem to fit the bill; allowing me to click the dialog.
Any help would be appreciated (and I am not limiting answers to any function. So please, let me know what ideas you have).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that angular isn't loading since the dialog pops up before the page loads. The below code tells protractor not to wait for angular to synchronize and then resume synchronization after the dialog box is clicked.

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.get("http://www.google.ca").then(function () {
    element(dialogIdentifier).click();
});
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
```

Comment: Ha, funny because this was what I attempted immediately after posting this and it was to no avail, it error-ed out.  I will try again to give you the error message.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: OK, then again, never mind I just tried it my code was off the first time and another error was generated by another mistake I was making.